# If $V = W_1\oplus W_2$ then the minimum polynomial of $T: V \to V$ is the $\gcd $ of the minimum polynomial of $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V = W_1\oplus W_2$ and $T: V \to V$, then the minimum polynomial of $T$ is  the $\gcd$ of the minimum polynomial of $W_1$ and $W_2$.
I know that the minimal plonynomails of $W_1$ and $W_2$ must divide the minimal polynomails of $T$, but how do I can conclude that is the $\gcd?$

I appreciate any hint!

Comment: Let $p$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$ over $V$, and let $v \in V$ be arbitrary. We can write $v = w_1 + w_2$ for $w_1 \in W_1$, $v_2 \in W_2$. Then consider $p(T)(v_1 + v_2)$. Can you see how to show that this evaluates to $\mathbf{0}$?

Comment: @Mark, indeed I can't. But I understand what you are saying, what you are trying to show! How can I show that this evaluates to $0$?

Comment: I imagine that $P(T) = \sum_i\alpha_iT^i$. Then, $P(T)(v_1 + v_2) =  \sum_i\alpha_iT^i(v_1 + v_2) = \sum_i\alpha_iT^i(v_1) +  \sum_i\alpha_iT^i(v_2) = 0 + 0.$

Comment: The first step is to use the fact that $p(T)$ is a linear operator, so $p(T)(v_1 + v_2) = p(T)(v_1) + p(T)(v_2)$. Then for the first term, for example, we factor $p(T) = q(T)p_1(T)$, where $p_1(T)$ is the minimal polynomial for the operator $T$ restricted to $W_1$. Can you see how to finish from here?

Comment: great, I think I can:
$p(T) = q(T)p_1(T) + r(T)p_2(T)$.
But then, $p = q.p_1 + r.p_2$ that is exatcly the $\gcd$, right?

Comment: The factorisation you have written isn't unique - you would need to specify what $q(T)$ and $r(T)$ are. If you follow the approach I suggest above, you'll get $p(T)(v_1) = q(T)p_1(T)(v_1)$. Can you see what this is equal to, and can you see how to deal with the $p(T)(v_2)$ term in a similar way?

Comment: I understand that $p$ must be divided by the minimal polynomials $p_1, p_2$ just for looking at the matrix of such operador, but I can't see how to conclude your point, could you be more explicit? I encourage you to wirte an answer, once I can mark you answer as accepted, even if it were another hint, with some discussion I can get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(T)$ be the GCD of the minimal polynomials $p_1(T)$ and $p_2(T)$ of the operator $T$ on $W_1$ and $W_2$ respectively. Note then that there exist polynomials $q_1(T)$ and $q_2(T)$ such that $p(T) = q_1(T)p_1(T) = q_2(T)p_2(T)$.

Then given arbitrary $w \in W$, we can write $w = v_1 + v_2$ for some $v_1 \in W_1$, $v_2 \in W_2$. Note then that we have

$p(T)(w) = q_1(T)p_1(T)(v_1) + q_2(T)p_2(T)(v_2)$

Recalling that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are minimal polynomials of particular operators, you can then show that the above evaluates to 0 - can you see how?

This shows that the minimal polynomial of $T$ divides $p(T)$. But since the minimal polynomial must have $p_1$ and $p_2$ as factors, conversely we must have that $p(T)$ divides the minimal polynomial, and so $p(T)$ *is* the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Thank you, I understand why $p(T)(w) = 0$ and the end of your solution! Thanks a lot.